# Недоступность некоторых Знаков для просмотра в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки

В личном кабинете не все Знаки доступны, скажем так, для получения по ним информации касательно своего профиля.

То бишь, например, посмотреть свой прогресс по знаку "Непризнанный гений" я не могу - к нему, вероятно, нет доступа (хотя изначально создаётся впечатление, что его не существует).

[image: непризнанный гений]

Хотя, конечно, на [странице знаков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) прочитать общую информацию я могу.

Для сравнения, по полученному знаку Страж информация в этом окне есть:

[image: страж]

Также я могу посмотреть свой прогресс по ещё не полученному знаку Некромант:

[image: некромант]

Comment: Странно, а у меня не показывается ни Страж, ни Некромент. Вообще, там должны быть только знаки за метки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, там рядом есть знаки которые можно зарабатывать :-)

Comment: Не показывает скорее всего потому, что получение этого знака не зависит от пользователя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема сводится к производительности.

Некоторые знаки имеют большую вычислительную стоимость награждения и отслеживания в реальном времени для каждого участника. Такие знаки не отображаются в указанной панели.

[@Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263611/274323)

Comment: Почему в реальном времени? Можно ведь кешировать при расчёте награждения.

Comment: @Qwertiy Потому что пересчет прогресса по всем знакам для всех участников Stack Overflow убьет SQL–сервер. Кэширование тут не поможет.

Comment: Я имел в виду такое: когда-то (вроде раз в день) система проверяет, награждать ли участника. Вот в этот момент результат проверки можно закэшировать. Лишнего пересчёта вроде нет. Нагрузка на сервер тоже минимальная - отдать готовое значение.

Comment: @Qwertiy В этом то и загвоздка. Такой пересчет внесет неоправданную  нагрузку на сервер.

Comment: Видимо я чего-то не понимаю... Но ведь пересчёт же когда-то должен происходить, чтобы определить, награждать пользователя или нет. Награды-то выдаются.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я так понимаю, что одно дело - найти вопросы, набравшие рейтинг 10 и ещё не получившие награду за "Хороший вопрос", и другое - рассчитать для каждого пользователя, сколько ему до такой награды не хватает.

Comment: Под ответом, на который ссылается Николай, есть [список всех неотслеживаемых знаков](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273929/330339).

Comment: @Qwertiy Если вы интересуетесь нюансами реализации в коде, как мне кажется, лучше всего будет задать вопрос напрямую Oded на MSE.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, сообщество не хочет поощрять целевую работу на этот знак. Иначе автор начнёт жалеть о голосах, полученных за принятый ответ, а такое поведение не соответствует ценностям сайта.

Знаки "Скрытый талант" и "Непризнанный гений" - утешение для тех, кто пишет рабочие ответы, но почему-то не растёт по рейтингу.

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, нет смысла выбирать знак, который невозможно получить намеренно.

Предположим, он бы там был. Вопрос: что надо делать, чтобы получить этот знак?

Comment: я заметил его отсутствие ввиду банального интереса, сколько же ещё мне его "достигать". то бишь, цели исключительно ознакомительные

Comment: @lexxl, но ведь это выбор знака, а не просмотр. Кстати, тут в какой-то теме была ссылка на приложение, считающее прогресс знаков. Хотя не уверен, что оно этот умеет.